# Using maven dependency "util-compress" in Java

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I want to unzip a folder in Java using "**util-compress**" maven dependency . After adding the dependency to the pom, how to use it in java program. Can someone explain please ? I'm new to this field . Any proper tutorial guidance is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/mod-unzip/1.0.0-final

Answer (score 0):

Java comes with “java.util.zip” library to perform data compression in ZIp format. The overall concept is quite straightforward.

Read file with “FileInputStream”Add the file name to “ZipEntry” and output it to “ZipOutputStream“

Below link may help to u
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/

Comment: Thank you Vishal. But I need to do it with maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using below dependency.

```
<dependency> <groupId>com.madgag</groupId> <artifactId>util-compress</artifactId> <version>1.33</version> </dependency>
```

This dependency internally deals with below dependencies

```
      <dependencies>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-codec</groupId> <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId> <version>1.4</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
<artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version> 
</dependency>
 <dependency> 
<groupId>commons-io</groupId> <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId> <version>2.0</version> 
</dependency>
 </dependencies/>
```

So you can find examples in below link 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html

Comment: Nope , I'm using [link] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/mod-unzip/1.0.0-final .

Comment: Hey I found one link in github for which you are using 
https://github.com/vert-x/mod-unzip?files=1

Comment: Thanks dude. Btw can you give me some guidance how we use it in java . assume I know nothing in maven

Comment: Maven is application building tool . its like it adds all the required dependencies to our applications.
Dependencies nothing but libraries. So we use XML format or else other scripting lang like groovy etc.
We fill the dependencies in pom.XML ,when we build the app libraries will be added to our app

So please follow this link for more detail explaination
https://www.javatpoint.com/maven-example